# How do perform declare on switch/case?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I very new beginner in Java
Please help!

I need to declare "chk" in order to let switch know where to go.

How can I declare in something like this in order to let the switch know I need to check all 4 output and display them accordingly, not just output 1:

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk1);
switch (chk.getId()) {
    case R.id.chk1:
        findViewById(R.id.output1).setVisibility(visible);
        break;
    case R.id.chk2:
        findViewById(R.id.output2).setVisibility(visible);
        break;
    case R.id.chk3:
        findViewById(R.id.output3).setVisibility(visible);
        break;
    case R.id.chk4:
        findViewById(R.id.output4).setVisibility(visible);
        break;
}
```

Comment: can you copy paste your code ? i dont see the image

Comment: show your code to get exact idea about it

Comment: CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk1);

        switch (chk.getId()){
            case R.id.chk1:
                findViewById(R.id.output1).setVisibility(visible);
                break;
            case R.id.chk2:
                findViewById(R.id.output2).setVisibility(visible);
                break;
            case R.id.chk3:
                findViewById(R.id.output3).setVisibility(visible);
                break;
            case R.id.chk4:
                findViewById(R.id.output4).setVisibility(visible);
                break;
        }

Comment: You know the id is R.id.chk1, what is the purpose of the switch statement?

Comment: I actually have 4 checkbox id, chk1,chk2,chk3,chk4. I wanted to show visible on my output, once any of the 4 checkbox is ticked. when I clicked chk1, output1 will shown visible..... hope you understand my explanation of my needs

Comment: anyone? please help!!

Answer (score 1):

***The switch Statement***

Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

The following code example, SwitchDemo, declares an int named month whose value represents a month. The code displays the name of the month, based on the value of month, using the switch statement.

public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int month = 8;
    String monthString;
    switch (month) {
        case 1:  monthString = "January";
                 break;
        case 2:  monthString = "February";
                 break;
        case 3:  monthString = "March";
                 break;
        case 4:  monthString = "April";
                 break;
        case 5:  monthString = "May";
                 break;
        case 6:  monthString = "June";
                 break;
        case 7:  monthString = "July";
                 break;
        case 8:  monthString = "August";
                 break;
        case 9:  monthString = "September";
                 break;
        case 10: monthString = "October";
                 break;
        case 11: monthString = "November";
                 break;
        case 12: monthString = "December";
                 break;
        default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                 break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
}
```

}